# Can FSCalendar achieve this calendar view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently looking to achieve a calendar view like this

[image]

Can this be done using the FSCalendar library or there is a better alternative library/methods to achieve this ? There isn't much documentation that I can get about FSCalendar.

Comment: don't use FSCalendar , there is lot of bug .Select any other

Comment: @VinodKumar any that you would recommend to achieve the calendar view as above ?

Comment: Can't you do that with just two collectionViews?

Comment: https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSDayFlow